# The peculiar case of disappearing data

Tags: d

I am trying following code:

```
import std.stdio; 
import std.range; 

void main(){
    auto data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];     // putting auto instead of int[][] here makes no difference; 
    auto coldata =  data.transposed;
    writeln("coldata: ", coldata);          // prints ok; 
    writeln("transposed data: ", coldata);  // Empty list is printed. Data disappears/evaporates!
}
```

The output is:

```
$ rdmd evapor.d
coldata: [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
transposed data: []
```

In the second call, an empty list is printed. The data seems to just disappear/evaporate!

Why the data is not priting on second call?

Edit: Empty list is printed even if I call transpose each time:

```
writeln("coldata: ", data.transposed);          // prints ok; 
writeln("transposed data: ", data.transposed);  // data disappears / evaporates!
```

Also, using `coldata.dup` does not work. I produces following error:

```
soq_evapor.d(10): Error: template object.dup cannot deduce function from argument types !()(Transposed!(int[][], cast(TransverseOptions)0)), candidates are:
/usr/include/dmd/druntime/import/object.d(3169):        object.dup(T : V[K], K, V)(T aa)
/usr/include/dmd/druntime/import/object.d(3206):        object.dup(T : V[K], K, V)(T* aa)
/usr/include/dmd/druntime/import/object.d(4482):        object.dup(T)(T[] a) if (!is(const(T) : T))
/usr/include/dmd/druntime/import/object.d(4508):        object.dup(T)(const(T)[] a) if (is(const(T) : T))
Failed: ["/usr/bin/dmd", "-v", "-o-", "soq_evapor.d", "-I."]
```

Comment: The call to writeline is probably probably consuming the range, with nothing left afterwards. If you write `data.transposed` twice in a row is it fine?

Comment: No! Even when I use ` writeln("transposed data: ", data.transposed);` in second line, an empty list is printed.

Comment: The range was consumed. You will need to call "save" before interacting with it.

Comment: How do you call `save`?

Answer (score 2):

The range is being "consumed". If you need to reuse it like you have, you will need to make sure to call `save` before you use it.

https://forum.dlang.org/post/migwtldccpwryusyolkq@forum.dlang.org
https://forum.dlang.org/post/n2m1jl$2dqf$1@digitalmars.com

You can find more info about this here: https://forum.dlang.org/thread/plsuntcmsezxpjbxkfnz@forum.dlang.org

```
import std.stdio; 
import std.range; 

void main(){
    auto data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];     // putting auto instead of int[][] here makes no difference; 

    auto coldata =  data.dup();
    auto otherData =  data.dup();

    writeln("coldata: ", coldata.transposed);          // prints ok; 
    writeln("transposed data: ", otherData.transposed);  // this also prints ok.

}
```

is one such way of doing this.

The main reason for doing this is how the API is designed in D. Not all ranges are destructively iterated, it just depends on the kind. In general, though you can.

The D Lang site has this to say:

> Most of the ranges in the standard library are structs and so foreach iteration is usually non-destructive, though not guaranteed. If this guarantee is important, an specialization of an InputRange can be used— forward ranges with a .save method:

https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/basics/ranges

Comment: `coldata.dup` produces error. Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: I am not able to make either `.dup` or `.save`. Can you give some code that works.

Comment: You mean `transposed` function can be used on a data only once. Also, the result of `transposed` can be used only once! It will be useful if you can briefly mention why there is so much restriction? (I have corrected a comment in your code).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am sorry for not being clear -- I will write more into the answer to clarify this. It's just the design of the language, I'm not a D Expert so I can't comment on why the API is designed this way. The reason it is "used" though is `writeln` iterates it to print it.

Comment: Iterates and consumes. `Writeln` does not consume most other type of data. Why here?

Comment: It's because of the underlying data type. _Some_ of the ranges are destructive when iterated. `foreach` is being called internally to iterate over the range (in order to print it) You can read the documentation for the range you are using to see if it would be destructively iterated.